# UITabBar and back button disappears in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, ios9

In iOS 9, when I segue from a table to a navigation controller, the nav bar and the tab bar disappear. As a result, my users will be hosed. How to fix it?

My StoryBoard structure is basically this:

```
->Tab Bar Controller->Nav Controller->Table View->Nav Controller->Table View->....
```

When I select a row in the first table view, the segue occurs, but the tab bar and back buttons disappear.

[image: ios 8] ----> [image: ios 9]

Notice the missing parts in the right picture.

DTS request has been filed, bug was reported months ago etc.

Comment: you can't house a navigation controller in another navigation controller in swift 2/xcode 7

Comment: I went through the same thing, this wasn't a problem in Xcode 6, and when I housed a nav controller inside another, my tool bar and nav bar disappeared and the view was presented modally rather than pushed

Comment: Mike - thank you! Wow - all this time and I had a stupid and redundant Nav controller!!!! If you make this an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as I stated, you can't nest a navigationController within a navigationController, or you will see this undesired behaviors. While you were able to slide somehow in Xcode 6/swift 1.2 with doing this, Xcode 7 has caught up to many loopholes.

Comment: Just a practical tip, for folks who go back to old storyboards and remove some of these redundant nav controllers.  Don't forget to look in prepareForSegue in case you have code that expects the destination VC to be a nav controller. Update that to expect the "true" destination.