# iOS9 after sege can't go back to previous viewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, ios9

I have a main View controller that is a UITableView that holds posts, so if a user clicks on a post, you would be able to see the post in more detail and comment on it. I just had that if the user pressed the cell, it would be redirected to the new view controller so that you could see the post in detail, and it automatically added the back button function on the navBar. After iOS9 update, I cannot go back. I'm not writing any code for that, I'm just using the push method, which worked fine on iOS8, but not on iOS9. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: There is no change in functionality here, so you need to explain in detail what you are seeing and what you are doing. Just waving your hands like this is not enough for you to get any help.

Comment: @matt I found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673944/uitabbar-and-back-button-disappears-in-ios-9 after posting this and browsing some more. Apparently we can't nest a navController within a navController. But after me trying fix this, it gives me a new error since it's not passing data anymore for some reason

Comment: That's excellent! Yes, that's right, you should never have been pushing a nav controller into a nav controller. Only Apple is allowed to do that. :) It was a bug that permitted it, and now they've closed that loophole. Obviously now you'll have rearchitect everything.

Comment: @matt I still think it's a little bit unfair for us, but I just did a work around on my app for now. A button that just closes the view controller so that for now it works until I find a better way to pass the data since it's not being transferred without the navController

Comment: Good that you solved it. You should probably delete this question, since it turns out to be a duplicate.