# iOS 9 back barButtonItem not showing on navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

Similar to the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673944/uitabbar-and-back-button-disappears-in-ios-9), with the exception that my `TabBar` is actually showing the `BackButton` on my `NavigationBar` is not. In the question I provided a link to the answer that solved the problem was that there was a `NavigationController` within a NavigationController, I do not have that so this is a different issue.

The basic flow of my `storyboard` is Login (`UIView`) - `TabBar` (`UITabBarController`) - `NavigationController` (`UINavigationController`) - Actual visible screen (`UITableViewController`) - New `TableView` where the issue occurs (`UITableViewController`).

On the new actual visible `screen` or the `TableView` the `NavigationBar` at the top shows just fine and I can click in the general area that the `BackBarButton` should be and it will go back, but no `BackBarButton` item is visible.

I tried changing the color, allocating it in the previous `ViewController`, making sure it was visible, etc. And none of them have shown the `Back Button`. It seems to be there but it is not shown.

Any ideas? From the other question that is similar to my issue this seems to be a `iOS 9` specific thing.

**EDIT** from looking at the Debug View Hierarchy I can tell that the back button is in fact there but it just has no label or back arrow on it. **How can I make the back label visible?**

**EDIT 2** 
Here is the `viewDidLoad` method of the view controller where the back button should appear.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];

    [self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    // Other unimportant stuff
}
```

The way I am segueing to this view controller is through the storyboard with a Push segue. Code is below.

```
- (void)segueToUser: (UIButton*)button {
    long row = button.tag;
    PFObject *PFQuote = [_recent quoteAtIndex:(row-1)/2];
    PFUser *u = [PFQuote objectForKey:@"creator"];
    _send = u;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showUser" sender:self];
}
```

Here is my `prepareForSegue` in the same file as the `segueToUser`

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showUser"]) {


        BRETTFUserTableViewController *bfutvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
        bfutvc.us = _send;
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of a section of my storyboard.
The **first** view is a `tabView`
The **second** view is a `navView`
The **third** view is a `tableView`
The **fourth** view is a `tableView`

[image]

Since no one has seemed to have found a solution I will provide additional information. From my digging deeper into the Debug View Hierarchy I have found some more information regarding the backButton. I can see that the back arrow is intact there and there is a `NSString` next to it that seems to be `nil`, I do not know why it is nil but that is what I found. Here are additional pictures of what I have found.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Try _Debug View Hierarchy_, if you're not familiar with it, [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/98356/view-debugging-in-xcode-6) might help.

Comment: From within the Debug View Hierarchy the button **IS** there but it is just a blank space. From this I can tell that he button is intact there but there is just no label on it. But I have tried setting the table programmatically but it still does not appear. @4oby

Comment: Put some code what you are doing to push a view-controller. After then any one will able to figure out the problem instead of description.

Comment: Added code @Krupanshu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the issue. To accomplish this I had to go into the navigation bar for the first `tableViewController` and set the Back Button title to `Back` and then set the tint color (as it defaulted to clear) and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

In your

> - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

you have Write a code line

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

In Above line you have set title " " **Empty String**.

Instead of empty string use the title which you want to show on back-button item. fr ex:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Check it might that help.

Adding a image of storyboard, how i have embedded the view controller in navigation controller.

[image]

or in case if you have put navigation appearance code anywhere in your app then also post that code.

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it @Wolverine

Comment: I added a picture of a part of my storyboard @Wolverine

Answer (score 0):

In your **viewDidLoad** and **prepareForSegue** methods you have this :

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Which replace the default back button of the navigation controller by a button without a label.

You should simply remove these 2 lines to have the default back button.

Comment: No it did not work, the only reason I added that stuff is because the default back button was not there. @Macistador

Comment: Well, it should be if your segue is of "push" type. If not I recommend to not try to add it manually but to find what makes it empty / hidden

Comment: Are you referring to the navigation to 1st tableview or 1st tableview to 2nd tableview @Macistador